# I didn't get the image printed from PIL but I got it from the matplotlib why?

Tags: image, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

w, h = 512, 512
data = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
data[0:256, 0:256] = [255, 0, 0] # red patch in upper left 
img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
img.save('my.png')
img.show() #why imshow didn't work?
```

Is this code OK or was it a problem as I had stored numpy array as the image data input?

Comment: I think you just had a typo... Your post was unclear, and I approved an edit of other user. After approving it, I saw most of your original code is gone, so I edited the post myself. But now it looks like `img.show()` is working fine. Isn't it?

Comment: yes its working.thank you.